# Constant inside and outside of the absolute value

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, mathematics

In my script (regarding a topic in electrodynamic) the following equation is given:

$$\frac R {r'}\frac{1}{|\vec r -\frac{R^2}{r'^2}\vec r' |}=\frac{1}{|\frac {r'} {R} \vec r -\frac{R}{r'}\vec r'|}$$

But shouldn't $\frac R {r'}$ enter the absolute value as $\frac {r'^2} {R^2}$ ?

Comment: I don't know what the question has to do with differential geometry. Maybe you  should change it to homework-and-excercises.

Comment: I don't know what the question has to do with Physics.

Comment: If $\mathbf a \in \mathbb R^3$ and $\lambda\ge 0 \in \mathbb R$ prove that : $\lambda\Vert \mathbf a \Vert = \Vert\lambda\mathbf a \Vert$. Is this a Physics question to answer ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should learn the différence between the **absolute value** of a scalar, i. e., a number (which is equal to this number if it is positive or zero, and its opposite if it is negative or zero, since $-0=0$), on the one hand, and the **modulus** of a **vector**, which is **not** a vector, but a scalar, on the other hand.
If the vector is a position vector, like here, the modulus is just its **length**. But there are many kind of vectors, and the word "length" would be meaningless for the vectors of type "velocity", "acceleration", "electric field", etc. etc. , hence the word "modulus" that applies to all vectors.

Both the absolute value and the modulus are **represented** by the same symbol, namely between $| \  | $, but they are totally different operations, one acts on a number, the other one on a vector. Casual inspection of your question shows that there are vectors between the $| \ |$, so this is all about modulus, not absolute value.

Next there is no reason to take the square of the outside factor, because it does not enter into a square root. I remember your initial post indeed contained a wrong expression, but apparently you corrected it while I was typing.

The exact answer is indeed

$${|\frac {r'} {R} \vec r -\frac{R}{r'}\vec r'|}$$

In general, for both absolute values and modulus, if you have a scalar $A$ of unknown sign before $| \ |$, then provided it is not zero,

$A | whatever |= A/|A|\  | A \times whatever |$,

where $A/|A|$ is $1$ if $A$ positive, and $-1$ if $A$ is negative. In $A=0$ then $| A \times whatever |=0$, but $A/|A|$ is meaningless.

Comment: If $\mathbf a \in \mathbb R^3$ and $\lambda\ge 0 \in \mathbb R$ prove that : $\lambda\Vert \mathbf a \Vert = \Vert\lambda\mathbf a \Vert$. Is this a Physics question to answer ???

Answer (score 1):

No, the only thing that cannot enter is a negative value, because the absolute value will never output a negative value. So as long as $\frac{R}{r'}$ is not negative what your script says is correct, because the absolute value doesn't do anything to the actual number, it just changes its sign. Therefore, you cannot introduce $\frac{R}{r'}$ with a square, because that is not the inverse of the absolute value.